# How to fix iOS 13.6 not supported by XCode 11.7 error?

Tags: ios, xcode

The details of the error are as follows:

```
The current device configuration is unsupported. 
This iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (Model A1584) is running iOS 13.6 (17G68), which is not supported by Xcode 11.7.
Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
Code: 601
Recovery Suggestion: To run on this device, please update to a version of Xcode that supports iOS 13.6. You can download Xcode from the Mac App Store or the Apple Developer website.
```

```
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
    DeviceType = "iPad6,7";
}
```

```
Unable to locate ideal DDI for platform: <DVTPlatform:0x7fcfe15b6570:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0x7fcfe15b64f0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform'>>, version: 13.6, build: 17G68
Domain: com.apple.dt.DVTDeviceSupportFilesError
Code: 2
```

```
User Info: 
{
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
}
```

**System Information**

```
macOS Version 10.15.6 (Build 19G73)
Xcode 11.7 (16142)
```

From the apple developer website I know we can use 13.6 and 13.7, but the error I receive says different.

[Apple Developer Website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-11_7-release-notes) .

Any suggestions?

Comment: the question won't let me add an answer as its currently closed. Solution - Update your iPhone/iPad and problem solved. see here - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-11_7-release-notes to see the interchanging compatibility between Xcode and iOS

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I had this issue with XCode 11.6 and 11.7, while the latter should work with iOS 13.6 and 13.7. My iPad is 13.6 and it's up to date, according to it's settings.

Comment: I also assumed that it should but it does not for some reason. Eventually, I was going to update my iPad and iPhone anyway, so, just decided to go with the recommended OS version. Don't want to mess around trying to understand why Apple does what it does :P

Comment: Apparently, I'm not the only one and found the issue on other websites, including Apple's developer. [StackExchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400716/iphone-7-plus-running-ios-13-6-1-not-supported-by-xcode-11-7)    -----------------    
[Apple](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/659043) . Have to find a way to update the device to 13.7